# best method to solve Nullable object must have a value in datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, nullable

I have a function that get the datetime value and it converts the datetime to a string as you can see here :

```
 public string ConvertToPersianToShow(DateTime? datetime)
        {
            if (datetime.HasValue)
            {
                PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
                string date;
                string year = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetYear(datetime.Value));
                string Month = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetMonth(datetime.Value));
                string day = Convert.ToString(persian_date.GetDayOfMonth(datetime.Value));

                date = year + "/" + Month + "/" + day;
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                return
                    "ثبت نشده";
            }
        }
```

as you can see here the `ConvertToPersianToShow` accepts an argument and the argument can be null so

```
 string startdate = callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.StartDate.Value);
```

sometimes this value can be null `item.StartDate.Value` so and i got this error :

```
Nullable object must have a value.
```

so i have to check `item.StartDate.hasvalue` in  the first line of my code to prevent the error.

is there any best method that i can use that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ConvertToPersianToShow` accepts a nullable `DateTime` and it checks if it has a value or not, you can just call it with the nullable object itself instead of its underlying value:

```
string startdate = callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.StartDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **item.StartDate** is null and you try to get its value by **item.StartDate.Value**. use this:

```
string startdate = callenderRepository.ConvertToPersianToShow(item.StartDate);
```